# Color changes based on what number is listed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote an if statement that says if the number is < 50 the background color is red. If the number is 51-74 it is orange and if it is 75 or up it's green. But the colors aren't changing based on the value and I'm not sure why. 
Here's the site in action: http://www.andrewhnovak.com/test/index.html
Here's the code
HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Site Demo</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/mainPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div><!--
</div>


</div>

</div>
-->

    <div class="container">
        <div class='underHeader'></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class='whiteBox'>
            <div class='newProducts'></div>
            <div id="frontPage">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tablehere">
    <thead>


        <tr>



        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row1Rating">62</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row2Rating">55</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row3Rating">77</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row4Rating">66</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row5Rating">88</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row6Rating">22</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row7Rating">22</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row8Rating">22</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row9Rating">22</div></th>

        </tr>
         <tr>
          <th data-field="id">item<div id="Row10Rating">22</div></th>


        </tr>
   <tr>
      <div id="link"><a href="#">Test showing app.js is connected</a></div>

        </tr>

    </thead>

</table>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>

      <footer></footer>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--<script src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
     <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
   $(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
    $('#frontPage').hide();

frontPageRatings();


});


function frontPageRatings(){

    var rowValue1 = document.getElementByID("Row1Rating");
    var Value1 = parseInt(rowValue1.innerHTML);

    var rowValue2 = document.getElementByID("Row2Rating");
    var Value2 = parseInt(rowValue2.innerHTML);

    var rowValue3= document.getElementByID("Row3Rating");
    var Value3 = parseInt(rowValue3.innerHTML);

    var rowValue4 = document.getElementByID("Row4Rating");
    var Value4 = parseInt(rowValue4.innerHTML);

    var rowValue5 = document.getElementByID("Row5Rating");
    var Value5 = parseInt(rowValue5.innerHTML);

    var rowValue6 = document.getElementByID("Row6Rating");
    var Value6 = parseInt(rowValue6.innerHTML);

    var rowValue7 = document.getElementByID("Row7Rating");
    var Value7 = parseInt(rowValue7.innerHTML);

    var rowValue8 = document.getElementByID("Row8Rating");
    var Value8 = parseInt(rowValue7.innerHTML);

    var rowValue9 = document.getElementByID("Row9Rating");
    var Value9 = parseInt(rowValue7.innerHTML);

    var rowValue10 = document.getElementByID("Row10Rating");
    var Value10 = parseInt(rowValue7.innerHTML);




    if(Value1<50){
        rowValue1.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
        }
        else if(Value1 >49 && Value1 <75){
        rowValue1.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
        }
        else if(Value1>74){
        rowValue1.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }

            if(Value2<50){
        rowValue2.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
        }
        else if(Value2 >49 && Value2 <75){
        rowValue2.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
        }
        else if(Value2>74){
        rowValue2.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }

            if(Value3<50){
        rowValue3.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
        }
        else if(Value3 >49 && Value3 <75){
        rowValue3.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
        }
        else if(Value3>74){
        rowValue3.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }

            if(Value4<50){
        rowValue4.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
        }
        else if(Value4 >49 && Value4 <75){
        rowValue4.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
        }
        else if(Value4>74){
        rowValue4.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }

            if(Value5<50){
        rowValue5.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
        }
        else if(Value5 >49 && Value5 <75){
        rowValue5.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
        }
        else if(Value5>74){
        rowValue5.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }

            if(Value6<50){
        rowValue6.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
        }
        else if(Value6 >49 && Value6 <75){
        rowValue6.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
        }
        else if(Value6>74){
        rowValue6.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }

            if(Value7<50){
        rowValue7.style.backgroundColor = '#900000';
        }
        else if(Value7 >49 && Value7 <75){
        rowValue7.style.backgroundColor = '#FF9933';
        }
        else if(Value7>74){
        rowValue7.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }



    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drastically simplify your code by adding the same class (for example rating) to each element that you want to color based on the value.

Then in jQuery you can query for all elements with the class rating, and interate over them.

Your javascript will then look something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    $('.rating').each(function(i, el) {
        var value = parseInt($(el).html(), 10);
        var color = getColor( value );
        $(el).css('background', color);
    });

    function getColor( value ) {
        var color = '#00CC00'; // value bigger than 74
        if(value < 50){
            color = '#900000';
        } else if(value > 49 && value < 75){
            color = '#FF9933';
        }  
        return color;
    }
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5yrdgj7h/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should change all of your `div` elements to use `id` attributes instead of `class` attributes and then use `getElementById` to access those elements.  For example:

```
<th data-field="id">item<div id="Row2Rating">55</div></th>
```

and then in the javascript:

```
var rowValue2 = document.getElementById("Row2Rating");
```

A class is used to describe a group of similar elements to style them all the same way, and uses `getElementsByClassName` to locate all of the elements that share the class.  An `id` should be a unique identifier and uses `getElementById` to select that unique element.

Comment: I changed them all to IDs, but the colors are still not changing. Why is that? I updated the code and updated the site link http://www.andrewhnovak.com/test/index.html

Comment: you are still using `getElementsByID`, which is plural.  You need to use `getElementByID` which is singular.

Comment: I didn't see that thanks. I updated code above and site link, but it's still an issue though

Comment: okay, you copied a lot of them beyond 7 they are all the same...and it should be Id not ID, my bad.  Answer updated.

Comment: Overall, though, you should really think about completely rewriting this as a reusable function that you call on the element rather than copying and pasting the code 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

### use this

do not have to write much for a simple function,
I modified the code and have reduced drastically.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        $('#frontPage').hide();
        frontPageRatings();
    });
function frontPageRatings(){
    function getFirstCLS(elem){
        return document.getElementsByClassName(elem)[0];
    }
    function getHTML(CLASS){
        return parseInt(getFirstCLS(CLASS).innerHTML, 10);
    }
    function setCOLOR(CLASS, color){
        getFirstCLS(CLASS).style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    function ifELSE(elem){
        if(getHTML(elem)<50){
            setCOLOR(elem, '#900000');
        } else if(getHTML(elem) >49 && getHTML(elem) <75){
            setCOLOR(elem, '#FF9933');
        } else if(getHTML(elem)>74){
            setCOLOR(elem, '#00CC00');
        }
    }
    ifELSE("Row1Rating");
    ifELSE("Row2Rating");
    ifELSE("Row3Rating");
    ifELSE("Row4Rating");
    ifELSE("Row5Rating");
    ifELSE("Row6Rating");
    ifELSE("Row7Rating");
    ifELSE("Row8Rating");
    ifELSE("Row9Rating");
    ifELSE("Row10Rating");
    }
});
```